# REGEX .htaccess RewriteCond parameter forming

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, path

How do I specify in .htacess that I want an action to be performed for all URLs beginning with www.domain.com?
I thought about
 `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com(.*)$ [NC]`
but it's wrong.
Also tried
 `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com(?:.*)?$ [NC]`
but isn't any better.

Comment: where you want to redirect it?

Comment: to another domain, either homepage either similar URL, with the domain changed.

Answer (score 0):

You have chosen to check against HTTP_HOST and make a decision based on that. HTTP_HOST only contains the hostname requested, and no slashes or parts of the full URL. Because of that, I would remove the (.*) or (?:.*)? at the end of your RewriteConds and check again. At least, that's how I use it.

If you're attemping to redirect a www to a non-www (just guessing) and want to make sure the requested path is transferred, this is my code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\..* [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://nonwwwdomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

It uses a 301 "Moved Permanently" redirect for search engines.

Comment: Thanks, or dank je @Martijn;), I expected a mistake somewhere there. I don't want to redirect a www to a non-www, but redirect all the URLs beginning with www.domain.com (thus www.domain.com/abcd, www.domain.com/file.php and so on) to another domain. I'll try to use what you've suggested in a minute.